# drag into set jlabels/jbutton one movable jlabel/object by mouselistenr

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a game of battleships game. I have a problem with the matrix of jlabels that i want to deploy my ships in.
I created my ships with deffernt dimensions. Now I want to drag and drop this ships into the battlefield theSet of jlabels or jbutton (I tryed both).

---

The question is:
that is there any way to make my ships click more than one jbutton/jlabel at the same time and all of the selected can do the save actuon?

---

Thank you

Comment: You can only drop onto one target. However within that drop event you could fill more than one JLabel. But the best advice I can give you is to just use one component (JPanel) for the board that the player is seeing. It makes some things (like selected which square was clicked) more complicated, but it makes other things (like drag and drop and painting a background, painting boats across multiple boxes) much easier